# How do I extract the Drive letter from the result of EnumNetworkDrives

Tags: windows, vbscript, mappeddrive, login-script

I'm using EnumNetworkDrives to list out all the drives on a machine.  I'd like to determine which object in the collection is drive "X"

What object is returned in EnumNetworkDrives that has a property I can compare to a drive letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9zt39at(v=vs.85).aspx

> The EnumNetworkDrives method returns a collection. This collection is
>   an array that associates pairs of items — network drive local names
>   and their associated UNC names. **Even-numbered items in the
>   collection represent local names of logical drives**. Odd-numbered
>   items represent the associated UNC share names. The first item in the
>   collection is at index zero (0).